# How to start Document Viewer in maximized mode in IBM BPM

Tags: document, documentviewer, ibm-bpm

I found [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/f37f6f3c-d39f-49c9-884b-a1665b7e2ca3/entry/How_to_start_a_BPM_Document_Viewer_in_maximized_mode1?lang=ru) link, but it does not work. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

```html
'<style>
iframe {
height: 1050(for example)px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Add the aboove cosde in custom HTML